# Regex capturing several repeats of one group

Tags: python, regex

I have a sample text:

```
Lorem ipsum AB-CD-01 dolor sit amet, AB-CD-Foobar consectetur
```

I want to capture all phrases AB-CD-*. I was trying something like that:

```
pattern = re.compile("((AB-CD-\S+).*)*")
result = pattern.search(text)
print(result.groups()) # expected: ('AB-CD-01', 'AB-CD-Foobar')
```

I know it's rather simple and basic regex issue but I couldn't find any good solution.

Comment: Use `re.findall()` with regex [`(AB-CD-\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/bO5gT9/2)

Comment: Thanks! So is it not possible using `search()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simpler pattern with [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> **Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings**. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned **in the order found**. *If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group*. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

Sample code with the updated regex:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'AB-CD-\S+')
test_str = "Lorem ipsum AB-CD-01 dolor sit amet, AB-CD-Foobar consectetur"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
# => ['AB-CD-01', 'AB-CD-Foobar']
```

See [IDEONE](https://regex101.com/r/vK1eS5/1) and [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vK1eS5/1)

The [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) only finds the first occurrence, `re.findall` returns a list of matches (if no capturing groups are defined in the pattern - that is why I suggest removing them).